# Is it possible to send a packet with data/hex information you determine with a router?

Tags: networking, router, packet

For a school project I have a IoT infrastructure with a Hongdian H8922 router connecting to a power control unit and another kind of control unit. With a certain hex number and hash I can reboot the PCU remotely, the same goes for the other control unit.

My question is, is it possible to send a packet starting from the Hongdian H8922 router which I will be connected to from a remote location, that has a specific hex number and hash that I can provide? If this is possible through the command line of cisco routers because the platform is a web interface that opens a windows within the browser which allows me to telnet to the router or allows me to work with the router GUI.

I've tried looking for solutions but none have popped up so if anybody knows an answer to my question, I would be grateful.

Edit: added explanation of the connection platform.

Comment: You can put any information you want in a packet IP, both IPv4 and IPv6, do not care what is in the packet payload.

Comment: There are all sorts of ways to send network traffic (and each language has network libraries, but the question doesn't list one). You may want to take a look at scapy (https://scapy.net/), which is easy to get started with.

Comment: Well I might not have explained the situation clearly enough as i have just seen. I will edit it as the platform I use to connect remotely to the router uses a webinterface which opens a window that allows me to telnet or work with the GUI.